# Macbook Pro got stolen. Thief knows password. iCloud Keychain all compromised?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, security, password, keychain

My Macbook was stolen. And I think the thief knows my Macbook's login (admin) password (not Apple ID). (I know, very stupid of me)

Does that mean all my passwords stored in iCould Keychain are now compromised? I have now changed a majority of them.

I guess the only thing I can do is to pray that the thief just wiped out my hard drive (would be best), and not doing some funny business with my iCloud Keychains?

Comment: Change your iCloud password

Comment: Prayer is unlikely to hurt, but it's not the only thing you can do.  (Rob is right.  Maybe this is obvious, but have you tried logging in at www.icloud.com?  That's where you can change your password, if you're not too late.)